# Change the style of row in FlatList using SetNativeProps

Tags: react-native

```
    <FlatList
         data={this.state.bankDetail}
         renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.bankImgView(item, index)}
         keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
         horizontal={false}
         numColumns={4} 
    />



    bankImgView(item, index) {

            return (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.selectBank(item.image, item.text, index)}>
                    <View ref={"img"+index} style={{ backgroundColor:  "white", marginTop: 2.5, justifyContent: "center", marginLeft: 6, alignItems: "center", flex: 1, marginBottom: 2.5 }}>
                        <View  style={{ width: width / 4 - 8, height: 90, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
                            <Image source={{ uri:item.image }} style={{ height: 60, width: 60 }} />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        }


    selectBank(bankImage,bankName,index) {
           this.refs["img"+index].setNativeProps({ backgroundColor: "red" });
        }
```

I wanted to change the background color of a view using setNativeProps which is in flatList but it not changed , the error encounters "setNativeProps of undefined".So Please provide me the correct way for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Change `selectBank` function to

```
selectBank = (bankImage,bankName,index) => {
    this.refs["img"+index].setNativeProps({ backgroundColor: "red" });
}
```

You are accessing references in a function where `this` is changed and `this.refs["img"+index]` is undefined.

So change it accordingly to es6 so that `this` is bind automatically.